# confusing sentence "before I'd had a chance, my sister ran up ..."

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

Recently, I came across this sentence "*Before **I'd had a** chance to look at the letter, my sister ran up and pulled them out of my hand!*" (it's in the book "destination B1 grammar & vocabulary with answer key" unit 5 exercise F)

- The word "*Before*" mean "*my sister ran up*" happened before "*I'd had a chance*"
- But the tense told me the opposite. Because "*I'd had a chance*" is in past perfect tense, so it must happened before "my sister ran up".

could you explain me why they use tense like that. and can I just use past simple tense in both parts of this sentence?

Comment: I don't think most native speakers would notice a distinction between "Before I had a chance" and "Before I'd had a chance".

Comment: When they speak, some trivial things will be ignore. But I want to know for writing purpose.

Comment: People will write this in either way. The distinction is extremely minor, I"m not even sure how to describe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the past perfect is generally used to refer to an action that took place before the current point in a narrative about the past. For example:

> By the time that I arrived at the station, the train had already left.

However, in time clauses with *before* it is indeed possible to use the past perfect to refer to an action that took place *after* the current point.

Swan in Practical English Usage (p100) has the sentence:

> He went out before I *had finished* my sentence. (= before the moment
>   when I had completed my sentence.)

He continues:

> Note that in sentences like the last, a past perfect  tense can refer
>   to a time later than the action of the main verb. This is unusual.

This ngram ([before I had a chance, before I'd had a chance](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=before%20I%20had%20a%20chance%2Cbefore%20I%27d%20had%20a%20chance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbefore%20I%20had%20a%20chance%3B%2Cc0)) is evidence for Swan's contention that the past perfect tense in the *before-clause* is unusual.
Nevertheless, it is easy to find numerous authentic examples via Google search (and see the *Cambridge Grammar of English* example below):

> It was over before I'd had a chance to tell him enough times how much
>   we cared.
>
> It caused the cows to quit the feed before I'd had a chance to see all
>   the calves
>
> Before I'd had a chance to DJ, I was playing live sets with my
>   sampling keyboard
>
> I was already in love with this beer before I'd had a taste.
>
> Before I'd had lessons with Wendy I had no confidence driving.
>
> He threw out new ideas before I'd had time to absorb his previous
>   ones.

---

As to your second question, you can indeed use the past simple in both clauses. As Parrott in *Grammar for English Language Teachers* (p389) states in his section on *Tense and time conjunctions*:

> *After* and *before* contain precise information about the sequence of events and so we don't need to rely on the tenses to provide this
>   information. We can use the past simple tense in both clauses.
>
> - Your daughter left before you woke up.

The *Cambridge Grammar of English* (p60) provides a reason, why the past perfect (as opposed to the simple past) may nevertheless be preferred:

> - He died in hospital. And before *he'd gone* into hospital, he kept saying to my mother ... .
>
> The perfect aspect versions stress the completion of the event in the
>   *before-clause* and a break in time between the events in the two clauses. The present simple or past simple suggest a closer connection
>   between the two clauses.